# Project Specific PHP Error Log in Laravel Valet

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet, valet

I just wanted to log PHP errors inside laravel project folder using Valet.

For Example - in Apache2 we can add php error log path (in my case my project folder) in virtual host and every time we add `error_log($var);` that will log errors inside project folder.

is it possible to create PHP Error log in Valet like so ?

Comment: Go to `.valet/Log` and you will see:

    access.log
    , error.log
    ...

Hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: is it possible to specify log file folder based ?

Comment: @Saurabh I don't see access.log or error.log, only `nginx-error.log`. Also, the directory seems to be `~/.config/valet/Log`, not `~/.valet/Log`